# Store anonymous user selection temporarily until registration

Tags: views, users, sessions, cookies

I want to let my first time visitors to first select a city, which will control what they see in my site, so it should be stored where I can see it everywhere (views, search and when posting content) until the user registers which then I store it in the user profile for later use.

Is that possible without development?
if development is mandatory, what are the right steps to do so?

Comment: Have you considered using the [Smart IP](http://drupal.org/project/smart_ip) module? You could alter the site display based on the users location, without worrying about persistance.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.. I'll consider that I promise :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to let my first time visitors to first select a city.

okk... so is this selection apart of say their Registration Process, if so you have 0 code to write? or some other random landing page on the site you are funneling new traffic too ... in which case you have to write some code ...

Anyways I would:

- Add a field like `user_location` to their Account Profile fields under `Admin -> Account Settings -> Manage Fields` ... or use the [Profile](http://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module to add such a field to a profile. There are "location" contributed modules for location type drupal Fields as well ... not sure what or how you want to store a "city" reference (string, geocode, zip, country + city, whatever).
- Then that field will be available everywhere as apart of the `$user` object.

If, you want this field to be collected before a user has registered (or separate from the registration process -- any fields in a users account settings can be made *apart* of the registration process). I would:

- create a simple module and define a FAPI form with a country list. The [list_predefined_options](http://drupal.org/project/list_predefined_options) module may help you make this list and manage it in code ...
- store the value in the users Cookie session value. Upon login use [hook_user_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) to look for the cookie value on 1st login to update the account `user_location` field with the session value.

Good luck.